# Why grep is not getting last argument?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

This is a script that searches each line of a file ($1) into another file ($2):

```
val=$(wc -l < $1)

for ((i = 1; i <= val; i++))
do
        line=$(sed '$i!d' $1)

        if grep -q "$(echo $line)" $2
        then
                echo found
        fi
done
```

But it gets stuck in the if grep.

It behaves as if it's not getting the $2.

Comment: 99% of the time echo `$(echo $line)` is redundant, you can just use `$line`

Comment: Read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for how to read a file line-by-line in shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem was in how I was passing the line number in **sed**:

```
#!/bin/bash

val=$(wc -l < $1)

for ((i = 1; i <= val; i++))
do
        line=$(sed "$i!d" $1)
        if ! grep -q "$(echo $line)" $2
        then
                echo $line
        fi
done
```

This works fine, if you do:

```
./script file1 file2
```

It gives you the lines of the first file that are missing in the second.

Comment: Glad to see that you resolved the problem yourself. Accept an answer (checkmark left of each answer) to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

> a script that searches each line of a file ($1) into another file ($2)

No need to write your own script for that. Use `grep`'s `-f` option:

```
if grep -qf "$1" "$2"; then
    echo found
else
    echo not found
fi
```